# Replace value after split in javascript

Tags: javascript

Suppose the string:

"The | dog";

If I do in js:

```
var string;
string = "The | dog | and | apple";
string.split("|")[1];
```

The returns will be "dog". I should like to replace that, somelike this:

```
string.split("|")[1] = "cat";
```

And the string pass to be "The | cat | and |apple", knowing as string "dog" can be another value too.

It's possible?

Comment: It is possible, but not in one expression. You could use `replace()` though.

Comment: Can't you just use `.replace('dog', 'cat')` ?

Comment: This is one simple example, in produce i need to use split and I don't know the value, can be 123 or 456 and more...then, did I can't to do with replace

Comment: @cl3m - a `.replace` does not replace **all** instances. It only replaces the first instance. You can use `.replaceAll`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the individual array element and then use join to make a string again:

```
var string = "The | dog";

var DELIMITER = " | ";
var parts = string.split(DELIMITER);
parts[1] = "cat";
string = parts.join(DELIMITER);

// string === "The | cat"
```

Comment: Humm, okay, and if the String be "The | dog | and | apple", if I could want replace dog for another value, knowing dog can be another string too

Comment: Yeah, it will just replace the contents between the first and second `DELIMITER`. If you wanted to replace a different position you could change `parts[1]` to something else.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr=string.split('|');
arr[1]='cat'
var s=arr.join('|');
```

or using regular expressions

```
string.replace(/^([^\|]+)\|([^\|]+)/g,'$1|cat')
```